# Does anyone sell custom WPF controls on a per control basis?

Tags: wpf

Does anyone sell custom WPF controls on a per control basis? I don't want to spend $1000 or more to get one control. All I want is an animated Expander control. I haven't found any decent tutorials on how to create one, so I'm willing to buy one but I don't need a whole "package".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most control vendors package as a set of controls, not a single control, as there is a large cost involved with making the deployment packages.  Separating out controls into separate deployments would increase the overall development cost.

That being said, if you just want an animated expander, there are many articles online showing how to accomplish this, including [this one about animating the built in Expander via custom templates](http://mattserbinski.com/blog/animating-expander), [this one using events](http://ewilkerson.wordpress.com/2007/01/03/wpf-expander-control-cool-things-part-1-animation/), and [these](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AnimatingExpander.aspx) [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111586/How-to-create-an-animated-expander) articles.